# Custom View how to access variable?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-custom-view

I created custom view, on google maps I want to add on the top information what is the thing that user clicked, and I got big problem with custom view, how to access from the activity the variable.

```
 public class Shop extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView name;

    public Shop(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView();
    }

    public Shop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setContentView();
    }

    public Shop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setContentView();
    }

    private void setContentView() {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =    (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_display_brand, this);


        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop);
        name.setText(".");

  }

    public void shopSetText() {
        name.setText("PetShop");

    }

}
```

and I added to activity:

```
public class MapViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        Shop map = new Shop(getApplicationContext());

        map.shopSetText();
    }
```

'
Why can't I set name from shopSetText? now it display only "."

Answer (score 1):

***Change this:***

```
public void shopSetText() {
    name.setText("PetShop");
}
```

***To:***

```
 public void shopSetText(String sTextToSet) {
    name.setText(sTextToSet);
}
```

In your activity:

```
public class MapViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    Shop map = new Shop(getApplicationContext());

    map.shopSetText("Same text to set here. Lorem ipsum");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `shopSetText()` method of `Shop` class instead of doing

```
public void shopSetText() {
    name.setText("PetShop");

}
```

do

```
public void shopSetText() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_display_brand, this);
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop);
    name.setText("PetShop");

}
```

By doing like the first one(which you are doing right now) you have just created a `TextView` object called `name` but haven't found any `TextView` of your layout to be linked with it.You need to do the same for `shopSetText` method just like you did for `setContentView` method.

Comment: thanks, I did like that but it also did not help.

Weird is that I can change it only from constructor